# numpy multidimension array from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a `Pandas dataframe` and I chose some coluns from them and create two dataframe with same length:

```
series1 = df[['VAL1', 'VAL2', 'VAL3', 'VAL4', 'VAL5','VAL6']]

series2 = df[['OTHER_VAL1', 'OTHER_VAL2', 'OTHER_VAL3', 'OTHER_VAL4', 'OTHER_VAL5','OTHER_VAL6']]
```

After that i create two numpy array from each `DataFrame`

```
series_1_np = series1.values
series_2_np = series2.values
```

Both array shape looks like this:

```
(69193, 6)
```

I would like to reshape my `series1` to shape like:

```
(69193, 6, 6)
```

and would like to add each values from `series2` to the new expanded dimension.

I'm asking it because I would like to create a `Conv1D` keras model. Now i'm doing it this way:

I create a new dimension in my `series1`:

```
series1 = np.expand_dims(series1, axis=-1)
```

Then I create my model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=2 , kernel_size=3, strides=1, input_shape=(6, 1)) )
    ...
    ...
```

It's running, there isn't any problem with this. But, I have another feature set in my series2 and would like to send it to my model input.

How can I do that? Sorry but I can't even start it.

Thank you!

Thank you!

Comment: Please do your best to provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "add each values from series2 to the new expanded dimension"? Do you mean that you want each `series1[:,:,i]` to be equal to `series1[:,:] + series2[:, i]`?

Comment: You have `2 x (69193 * 6)` items in the two arrays.  The new shape you want has `(69196 * 6 * 6)` items.  Are you sure that is what you want?  Maybe explain what you are trying to do. Take a look at [Joining Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)

Comment: you have to imagine a dataframe which has 12 columns and 69193 rows. and i would like to create a numpy array from that, because it could be an input for  Conv1d Keras model.

Comment: sorry i'm going to update my question..

Comment: I'm afraid it's still quite unclear why you want the shape to be `(69193, 6, 6)`. What will be different about each of those 6 different `(69193, 6)`-sized arrays?

Comment: Series2 array values would be inside the new dimension.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a `(69193, 12)` sized array then, as @wwii said above.

Comment: I don’t think. :) or maybe I know it wrong. I would like something ldataset what is like the MNIST dataset.

Comment: You understand that if an array is `(69193, 6, 6)` then that is 6 times as many elements as a `(69193, 6)` array, right? But you are starting with only 2 different `(69193, 6)` arrays, so where do all those extra elements come from? Maybe you want a `(69193, 6, 2)` array?

Comment: Now as you write, yes, it should be (69193, 6, 2) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments the simplest way to get what you want is

```
series1_new = np.zeros((df.shape[0], 6, 2))
series1_new[:,:,0] = series_1_np
series1_new[:,:,1] = series_2_np
```

Comment: Maybe one of these would work also: [Joining Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays).